# Polymer paper-dialog - set size to full viewport in shady dom? Also, does this old article apply to shady dom?

Tags: polymer, shady-dom

I am using Poylmer 1.0, but I still read https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#cat. Does anyone know if the same logic applies to `Shady` dom?

I really like the way https://events.google.com/io2015/ did their video. It uses `paper-dialog` to display the video and takes the full viewport.

I am trouble making `paper-dialog` take the full viewport. As shown in the image, I can't seem to force it. I have tried `top: 0px; bottom 0px; left: 0px, right: 0px` but this will break the behavior. `fit` gives me the closest look you see in the image so far.

```
  <paper-dialog class="video-dialog fit">
   <div class="layout horizontal">
    <paper-button dialog-dismiss>
      <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-button>
  </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
      <google-youtube style="height: 100%;"
        video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
        rel="1"
        start="5"
        playsinline="0"
        controls="2"
        showinfo="0"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        autoplay="1">
      </google-youtube>
  </paper-dialog>
```

Questions, please:

1. Just to confirm, all the children of `paper-dialog` are in the
   `light dom`, correct?
2. To make the `paper-dialog` fill the view port like it was done in 
       https://events.google.com/io2015/, do I need to access the shady dom
       with `/deep/` or `::shady` to do this? It seems that `<paper-dialog
       class="fit">` would of done this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out....looked at the source code and found `margin` attribute there....I just changed it to 0px;